# Get sample data from a Cassandra table

Tags: filter, cassandra, production, partition

I have read access to a production Cassandra cluster.  I'd like to look at a sample row to understand the data a little better.  I don't know any of the partition keys to filter on and I'd rather not run any query that would impact the performance of the cluster (ie. allow filtering etc)

I don't have access to nodetool.

Are there any cqlsh queries that would allow me to just get some sample data from a table without knowing a partition key ahead of time to filter on?  Or a query that would give me a list of the partition keys that I can then use to filter on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect via cqlsh, you can use the `LIMIT` operator to limit the number of results returned with something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 10;
```

This would limit the number of records so you're not doing a full table scan.

Ideally however is that you either get (a) some sample data from the app team, or (b) connect to a non-production environment. Cheers!